# Difference between bitmap and bitmapdata

Tags: c#, image

What is the difference between `System.Drawing.bitmap` and `System.Drawing.Imaging.bitmapdata` in C#?
How to convert them to each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Bitmap` is an actual bitmap object. You can use it to draw to using a `Graphics` instance obtained from it, you can display it on the screen, you can save the data to a file, etc.

The `System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData` class is a helper object used when calling the `Bitmap.LockBits()` method. It contains information about the locked bitmap, which you can use to inspect the pixel data within the bitmap.

You can't really "convert" between the two per se, as they don't represent the same information. You can *obtain* a `BitmapData` object from a `Bitmap` object simply by calling `LockBits()`. If you have a `BitmapData` object from some other `Bitmap` object, you can copy that data to a new `Bitmap` object by allocating one with the same format as the original, calling `LockBits` on that one too, and then just copying the bytes from one to the other.

Answer (score -1):

Convert bitmap to bitmap data. Also refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspxhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

```
Private void LockUnlockBitsExample(PaintEventArgs e) { 
// Create a new bitmap. 
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\fakePhoto.jpg");
 // Lock the bitmap's bits.
 Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
 System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat); 
// Get the address of the first line.

 IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0; 
// Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.  
int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;

byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
 // Copy the RGB values into the array.
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes); 
// Set every third value to 255. A 24bpp bitmap will look red.  
 for (int counter = 2; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3) rgbValues[counter] = 255;
 // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
 // Unlock the bits.
 bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData); 
// Draw the modified image.
 e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 150); 
}
```